# Custom XML response for auth failure using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, devise

I'm using an XML POST to sign in my users and I need to return an XML response if the authentication didn't work. However, the format of the XML response needs to be custom, and I can't tell where in Devise I should change this output.

In my 'create' method for the 'user_sessions_controller.rb' I have the vanilla call:

```
def create
  resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, 
                                  :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
```

This is returned:

```
<errors> 
  <error>Invalid email or password.</error>
</errors>
```

but I need to put a wrapper around this:

```
<AppName>
  <errors>
    <error>Invalid email or password.</error>
  </errors>
</AppName>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can redefine `http_auth_body` method in your custom failure app:

```
# lib/custom_failure_app.rb

class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  protected
    def http_auth_body
      return i18n_message unless request_format
      method = "to_#{request_format}"
      if method == "to_xml"
        { :errors => { :error => i18n_message } }.to_xml(:root => Rails.application.class.parent_name)
      elsif {}.respond_to?(method)
        { :error => i18n_message }.send(method)
      else
        i18n_message
      end
    end
end
```

then add this to `initializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
end
```

and add this to `application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

result:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.xml -d "{}"                                                                 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DeviseCustom>
  <errors>
    <error>You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.</error>
  </errors>
</DeviseCustom>
```